# How to configure JDK environment path not JRE?

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu-16.04

I have install JDK 8 and my environment path is

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk"
PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin
```

Here is my Java version

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

I am getting problem while installing Maven on Ubuntu

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run `update-alternatives --config java` this should gives you the path to the java home.

After this you can set your JAVA_HOME path simply. Just edit your `~/.bashrc` and add this line `export JAVA_HOME=<path_given_by_the_command above>`. After this reload your bashrc.

Comment: The command out is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java` but where to set

Comment: Just edited the answer not it is more complete :) 
You reload your bashrc just open & close the terminal window or run `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I wrote a command `sudo nano /etc/environment` and paste `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java` still getting error

Comment: Not sure if this is enough did you tried to just type in `echo $JAVA_HOME` to look if the path was set correctly?

Comment: Yes path is set but getting same error when writing command as `mvn -version`

Comment: Did you tried [out this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391921/cannot-run-maven2-on-linux-ubuntu-12-04) - looks very similar to your problem.

Comment: Then i only have a last guess otherwise i don't know :( Try 
`cd /etc/profile.d/` and then edit with
`vim maven.sh` and simply add the `export JAVA_HOME...` to the maven file

Answer (score 1):

Once you have installed oracle JDK on your Ubuntu then run below command to set JDK as default

```
sudo apt install oracle-java8-set-default
```

This will set environment variable path and you don't need to change config files manually.

Comment: But still am getting same error while writing `mvn -version`

Comment: Have you installed oracle JDK8?

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the path using readlink

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(readlink -f /etc/alternatives/java | sed -e 's/\/jre\/bin\/java$//')"
```